# How to customize the database notifications?

Tags: laravel, database, notifications

I'm building a microservice over an old system that has its notification system. I'm using Laravel for this microservice and want to leverage its notification system after tailoring it to the old notification. the old system has these table fields:

```
[
        'id',
        'organization_id',
        'user_id',
        'time',
        'module',
        'title',
        'description',
        'text',
        'status',
        'payload'
];
```

How to make the database channel using this old table?

Comment: What are the other columns for? Have you considered adjusting the toArray method so that that info is in the JSON?